# Partial view doesn't get the object. always a null exception

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, razor-pages

My partial view

```
@page
@model TechManagement.Models.ProjectTask
```

Call from my edit page

```
  @foreach (TechManagement.Models.ProjectTask task in Model.Project.Tasks)
            {
    <partial name="Task" model="@task">
}
```

same happens for

```
@Html.Partial("Task", (TechManagement.Models.ProjectTask)task)
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete `@page` in you partial view.

Because `@page` makes the file into an MVC action.

Answer (score 0):

**TL&DR:**  When creating a PARTIAL do NOT add a @page modifer

**Explanation**: A partial is considered a 'dumb' page, because it only accepts input from the caller.  Due to this limitation, the partial does NOT need any modifiers outside of the @model  being passed in.

**Answer**:

```
@page  <-- REMOVE THIS LINE!!!!!
@model TechManagement.Models.ProjectTask
```